# ethernet card RTL8125 on Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop, no internet connectivity, no ipv4 address

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10. After my first reboot, there is no internet via ethernet (I helped myself with an old wifi stick). This is what I found out:

1.

```
    ~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
0f:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1849:8125]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

2. 

```
~$ ip l show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp15s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: wlxaca2137f9bfa: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:a2:13:7f:9b:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

3. 

```
~$ ifconfig 
enp15s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:aaa1:59ff:feec:ba7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:feec:ba7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46579  bytes 40502901 (40.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22370  bytes 4855246 (4.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 26380  bytes 2292970 (2.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26380  bytes 2292970 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxaca2137f9bfa: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:aa8c:be9f:e0ff:b362  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:e4a7:abbe:7116:ac05  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:21ee:a417:25a7:28e5  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::51dd:9aeb:5494:b7ef  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ac:a2:13:7f:9b:fa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 79599  bytes 97671453 (97.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48421  bytes 6691084 (6.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It shows up in my wifi router like this:

```
Name: a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d
IPv4: 192.168.0.80
IPv6: 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:5884:f3e5:1af4:20ca
MAC: a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d
Geschwindigkeit: 1 Gbps
Bemerkungen:
```

So it looks to me like it's getting a ipv6 address, but no ipv4 address. That's why I tried to turn off ipv6 with the following commands:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

It does not help. ifconfig then results in

```
~$ ifconfig 
enp15s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 47466  bytes 40630730 (40.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22423  bytes 4864695 (4.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Following [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/) advice I blacklisted the driver module r8169, because it supposed to be used mistakenly.

```
echo "blacklist r8169" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_r8169.conf
```

This results in the networkcard not showing up at all:

```
~$ ifconfig 
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:64:99:78:2d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 322  bytes 26855 (26.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 322  bytes 26855 (26.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Is the wrong kernel module being used?

```
~$ modprobe -c | grep 8125 | grep 10EC
```

alias pci:v000010ECd00008125sv*sd*bc*sc*i* r8169

**After using `dhclient -4 enp15s0` as dummyuser suggests, internet works and ifconfig shows**

```
enp15s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a02:810d:12c0:2758:aaa1:59ff:feec:ba7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::aaa1:59ff:feec:ba7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a8:a1:59:ec:ba:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 18089  bytes 11957535 (11.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7174  bytes 755765 (755.7 KB)
        TX errors 8  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`tail -200 /var/log/syslog | grep dhclient` results in

```
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: xid: warning: no netdev with useable HWADDR found for seed's uniqueness enforcement
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: xid: rand init seed (0x63d1fc16) built using gethostid
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp15s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xc0ef4636)
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.80 from 192.168.0.1
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.80 on enp15s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3646efc0)
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.80 from 192.168.0.1 (xid=0xc0ef4636)
Dec 30 15:00:39 gandalf-the-white dhclient[42914]: bound to 192.168.0.80 -- renewal in 286134 seconds.
```

Links
[1](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/): https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Howto/Realtek-r8125/

Comment: This does not look like a driver issue, as ipv6 seems to work. This is 22.10. `Server` or `Desktop`?  
(I’m focussing on server) Please edit your question add the network configuration. 
Please open a terminal and execute `dhclient -4 enp15s0`. Please do a `tail -20 syslog | grep dhclient` and add the output to your question. did `ifconfig enp15s0` change?

Comment: Thanks a lot, '''dhclient -4 enp15s0.''' solves the problem, see edit of my question. Do you know how to make this permanent?

Comment: make it permanent, this is a configuration issue, which depends on the version of ubuntu you use. server or desktop? this question is still open.

Comment: It's not very visible, but I added it to the title of the question. It's Ubuntu Desktop 22.10.